# Two Questions about Path Integral from "Gauge Fields and Strings" by Polyakov

Tags: quantum-mechanics, path-integral, point-particles, functional-determinants

My questions are about worldline path integrals from the book [Gauge Fields and Strings](https://books.google.se/books/about/Gauge_Fields_and_Strings.html?id=uaI8xcjJ8LMC&redir_esc=y) of Polyakov. On page 153, chapter 9, he says

> Let us begin with the following path integral
>   \begin{align}
> &\mathscr{H}(x,y)[h(\tau)]=\int_{x}^{y}\mathscr{D}x(\tau)\delta(\overset{\,\centerdot}{x}{}^{2}(\tau)\boldsymbol{-}h(\tau)) 
> \nonumber\\
> &=\int\mathscr{D}\lambda(\tau)\exp\left(i\int_{0}^{1}d\tau\lambda(\tau)h(\tau)\right)\int_{x}^{y}\mathscr{D}x(\tau)\exp\left(-i\int_{0}^{1}d\tau\lambda(\tau)\dot{x}^{2}(\tau)\right) \tag{9.8}\label{9.8} 
> \end{align}
>   where $h(\tau)$ is the worldline metric tensor.
>
> The action in (9.8) is invariant under reparametrizations, if we transform:
>   \begin{align}
> x(\tau)&\rightarrow x(f(\tau)) \nonumber\\
> h(\tau)&\rightarrow\left(\frac{df}{d\tau}\right)^{2}h(f(\tau)) \tag{9.9}\label{9.9}\\
> \lambda(\tau)&\rightarrow\left(\frac{df}{d\tau}\right)^{-1}\lambda(f(\tau))
> \end{align}

Polyakov continued with the following statement.

> It is convenient to introduce instead of the worldline vector $\lambda(\tau)$, the worldline scalar Lagrange multiplier $\alpha(\tau)$:
>   \begin{align}
> \lambda(\tau)&\equiv\alpha(\tau)h(\tau)^{-1/2} \nonumber\\
> \alpha(\tau)&\rightarrow\alpha(f(\tau)) \tag{9.11}
> \end{align}
>   So that:
>   \begin{align}
> &\mathscr{H}(x,y)[h(\tau)] \nonumber\\
> &=\int\mathscr{D}\alpha(\tau)e^{i\int_{0}^{1}d\tau\alpha(\tau)\sqrt{h(\tau)}}\int_{x}^{y}\mathscr{D}x(\tau)\exp\left(-i\int_{0}^{1}d\tau\frac{\alpha(\tau)\dot{x}^{2}(\tau)}{\sqrt{h(\tau)}}\right) \tag{9.12}
> \end{align}

1. ***My first question is about equation (9.12). What Polyakov did there is boldly replace the integral measure $\mathscr{D}\lambda$ by $\mathscr{D}\alpha$. Didn't he miss the Jacobian factor?***

$$\mathscr{D}\lambda=\mathscr{D}\alpha\det\left(\frac{\delta\lambda}{\delta\alpha}\right)$$

***My second question is the following.***

He introduced another parameter $t$, called proper time, defined as

> \begin{align}
> t\equiv\int_{0}^{\tau}\sqrt{h(s)}ds;\quad T\equiv t(1) \tag{9.13}
> \end{align}
>   and so
>   \begin{align}
> &\mathscr{H}(x,y)[h(\tau)]\equiv\mathscr{H}(x,y;T) \nonumber\\
> &=\int\mathscr{D}\alpha\exp i\int_{0}^{T}\alpha(t)dt\int_{x}^{y}\mathscr{D}x\exp-i\int_{0}^{T}\alpha(t)\dot{x}^{2}(t)dt \tag{9.14}
> \end{align}

2. ***Can anybody tell me how he derived the equation (9.14) via using the "proper time" parameter $t$?***

---

***New Edition***: As pointed out by @Qmechanics in his answer, equation (9.12) has a missing Jacobian factor. The correct path integral should be

$$\int\mathscr{D}\alpha(\tau)(h(\tau))^{-1/2}e^{i\int_{0}^{1}d\tau\alpha(\tau)\sqrt{h(\tau)}}\int\mathscr{D}x(\tau)e^{-i\int_{0}^{1}\alpha(\tau)\frac{\dot{x}^{2}(\tau)}{\sqrt{h(\tau)}}d\tau}.$$

On page 152, Polyakov started with the two point function

> \begin{align}
> &G(x,y)=\int\frac{\mathscr{D}x(\tau)}{\mathrm{Vol}\mathfrak{Diff}}\exp\left(-m\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\dot{x}^{2}(\tau)}d\tau\right) \tag{9.6} \\
> &=\int\frac{\mathscr{D}h(\tau)}{\mathrm{Vol}\mathfrak{Diff}}\exp\left(-m\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{h(\tau)}d\tau\right)\int\mathscr{D}x(\tau)\delta(\dot{x}^{2}(\tau)-h(\tau)) \tag{9.7}
> \end{align}

Then, using the above corrected result, one has 
\begin{align}
&G(x,y)=\int\frac{\mathscr{D}h(\tau)}{\mathrm{Vol}\mathfrak{Diff}}\exp\left(-m\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{h(\tau)}d\tau\right)\cdot \nonumber\\
&\cdot\int\mathscr{D}\alpha(\tau)(h(\tau))^{-1/2}e^{i\int_{0}^{1}d\tau\alpha(\tau)\sqrt{h(\tau)}}\int\mathscr{D}x(\tau)e^{-i\int_{0}^{1}\alpha(\tau)\frac{\dot{x}^{2}(\tau)}{\sqrt{h(\tau)}}d\tau}.
\end{align}

Therefore, one has

$$G=\int\frac{\mathscr{D}h(\tau)}{\mathrm{Vol}\mathfrak{Diff}}(h(\tau))^{-1/2}e^{-m\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{h(\tau)}d\tau}\int\mathscr{D}\alpha(\tau)e^{i\int_{0}^{1}d\tau\alpha(\tau)\sqrt{h(\tau)}}\int\mathscr{D}x(\tau)e^{-i\int_{0}^{1}\alpha(\tau)\frac{\dot{x}^{2}(\tau)}{\sqrt{h(\tau)}}d\tau}$$

The problem is that the jacobian factor $h^{-1/2}$ already breaks the reparametrization invariance of the effective action. How does the above path integral make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. It is perhaps helpful to realize that Polyakov is performing a worldline (WL) reparametrization (9.9) such that the metric component $h\equiv 1$ is identically equal to one in the new coordinate $t$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have one more question about the path integral. I edited my post. Would you please have a look at my new edition?